# Initialize Instabug without showing hint prompt

Tags: android, instabug

I need to initialize [Instabug](https://instabug.com/) in my Android application but do now want it to show the hint prompt saying "Shake your device etc." when user just opened the app. Instead I want to show that after user has already logged in.
I initialize Instabug with the following code:

```
    new Instabug.Builder(this, instaKey)
            .setInvocationEvent(InstabugInvocationEvent.SHAKE)
            .setShakingThreshold(1100)
            .build();
```

So is there a way to disable that hint prompt in a first place place? 
I tried to set `.setPromptOptionsEnabled(false, false, false)` but it seems this does not what I need. 
I cannot find any documentation about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable showing it by setting false to `setIntroMessageEnabled(boolean)` API example:

```
new Instabug.Builder(this, instaKey)
        .setInvocationEvent(InstabugInvocationEvent.SHAKE)
        .setShakingThreshold(1100)
        .setIntroMessageEnabled(false)
        .build();
```

and then whenever the User is logged in you can show the intro message by invoking it manually example:

`Instabug.showIntroMessage();`

And by the way the `.setPromptOptionsEnabled(true, true, true)` is used for controlling prompt Options visibility [talk to us, report a bug, send a feedback] as described in the official docs here: http://docs.instabug.com/docs/enabled-features

Comment: As of version 11.8.0 the method `showIntroMessage` is not available, use `Instabug.setWelcomeMessageState(WelcomeMessage.State.DISABLED)` instead. Reference: https://docs.instabug.com/docs/android-onboarding-experience